# Android Mediaplayer goes to an error when wifi switch off

Tags: android, error-handling, wifi, media-player, android-videoview

My problem is: I have a App with Videoview element. This streams a video from internet path. When I start the Video with Wifi there is no problem. When I switch off the internet the video gives error. I have implemented onErrorListener for videoview.

> V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-1
>   E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1)
>   V/MediaPlayer: callback application
>   V/MediaPlayer: back from callback

Just those errors seen above appear for 10 seconds and than the application crash. How can I handle this error.

Here are the errors. (Sorry! I could not format it)

> 02-17 23:09:56.867 337-7882/? E/OMXNodeInstance: setConfig(5230:SEC.mp3.dec, ConfigPriority(0x6f800002)) ERROR: UnsupportedIndex(0x8000101a)
>   02-17 23:09:56.877 337-7881/? E/NuPlayerDecoder: Stream error for OMX.SEC.mp3.dec (err=-1), EOS successfully queued
>   02-17 23:09:56.877 337-3864/? V/NuPlayer: decoder audio kWhatError
>   02-17 23:09:56.877 337-3864/? E/NuPlayer: received error(0xffffffff) from audio decoder, flushing(0), now shutting down
>   02-17 23:09:56.877 337-7881/? E/NuPlayerDecoder: Stream error for OMX.SEC.mp3.dec (err=-1), EOS successfully queued

Comment: post the crash log..

Comment: is it happening on every device or just on some of them?? Im developing a streaming audio app and havig the same problems with samsung phones

Comment: I have tested it on Samsung Phones.. Than it could be a samsung problem...!?